# Default for everyone in deployment package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

Is there any way to set the deployment package to select for everyone instead of just me as the default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you look at the Setup project properties then you will see an InstallAllUsers property - set this to true.

NOTE - Make sure you have the properties window visible as well as solution explorer. (View -> Properties Window)